# Send HTTP POST data without certificate verification and retrieve HTML data

Tags: java, url

I'd like to know how to be able to send a POST data to an HTTPS URL without SSL cert verification and how to retreive the html back (it's actually an xml data) back from that request.

so far i have the following:

```
public void sendPost(final String request, final String urlParameters) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(request); 
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches (false);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    connection.disconnect();        

}
```

so I need to know the following:

- how to ignore ssl cert verification
- how to retreive html data from that request

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to set your own `HostnameVerifier` on the `HttpsUrlConnection`:

```
connection.setHostnameVerifier( new AlwaysTrustHostnameVerifier() );
```

where

```
class AlwaysTrustHostnameVerifier implements X509TrustManager 
{
    public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] x509 , String authType ) throws CertificateException { /* nothing */ }
    public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] x509 , String authType ) throws CertificateException { /* nothing */ }
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }      
}
```

The point is that the `check*` methods should throw `CertificateException` if the cert chain isn't trusted, which in your case should just be ignored.

Cheers,

Comment: thank you. and how do I retreive the html data from that request ?

Comment: i'm confused when to open the input stream.. after or before the output stream.. doing some tests..

Comment: To talk HTTP with a server, I'd suggest you use one of several dedicated libraries. My preference is [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/)